# Passing a CComPtr to a function with a raw pointer prototype

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

I'm going through some legacy C++ code dealing with the Windows Imaging Component library and I observed this:

```
void setProperties(IPropertyBag2* const pBag)
{  
   pBag->Write(...);
}

void other_function()
{
   CComPtr<IPropertyBag2> pBag;
   //Code to initialize pBag
   setProperties(pBag);
}
```

The `setProperties` method simply writes a bunch of properties to the property bag.
The code compiles and runs fine because I think it calls the appropriate typecasting operator.

My question is whether such an interface is recommended or is there a better way of passing the pointer.
For example, is there any difference (in terms of safety/ performance) if the signature was changed to:

```
void setProperties(const CComPtr<IPropertyBag2>& pBag)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw interface pointers are the canonical way to work with COM objects. They are also the most flexible. Using a reference to a CComPtr will tie you into using CComPtr always.

Any COM pointer, even a dumb one, is automatically a smart pointer since the object itself implements `AddRef` and `Release`. If the function isn't keeping a copy of the pointer there's no need even to worry about that.

The CComPtr type will automatically cast itself to a raw pointer for convenience.

Comment: Using a CComPtr parameter won't tie you to using CComPtr always, because CComPtr constructors are not explicit. And raw interface pointers are not smart pointers. Forgetting to Release an object will cause it to leak. It has all the same problems as forgetting to `delete` memory allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many advantages to using a CComPtr parameter (unless it's non-const and you're going to modify it). CComPtr is more useful for local variables and instance variables.

But it's OK to do it, if only as a matter of style/consistency.